# Как добавить координатную сетку с динамическим добавлением ячеек по вертикали?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Есть поле с блоками, которые можно перемещать и менять их размер http://jsfiddle.net/qqzvjvfx/24/
Используются [angular-gridster.js](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster) и `flexbox`.

Пример кода:

```
  <div ng-app="someApp" ng-controller="someCtrl">
        <div gridster="gridsterOpts">
            <ul>
                <li class="" gridster-item="block" ng-repeat="block in sorted_blocks">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">{{ block.title }}</div>
                        <div class="panel-content image-responsive" 
                             ng-style="{'background-image':'url(' + block.image + ')'}"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Angular Controller:

```
   angular.module('someApp', ['gridster']).controller('someCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.gridsterOpts = 
        {
            resizable: {
                enabled: true
            },
            columns: 4,
            rows: 16,
            minRows: 4,
            margins: [0,0],
            floating: false
        };
        $scope.sorted_blocks = [{
            id: 1,
            sizeX: 1,
            sizeY: 1,
            image: 'http://i.imgur.com/NI1Xm16.jpg',
            title: 'title1',
            row: 1,
            col: 2
        }, {
            id: 2,
            sizeX: 2,
            sizeY: 1,
            image: 'http://i.imgur.com/x6qmeUY.jpg',
            title: 'title2',
            row: 0,
            col: 0
        }];
    });
```

Css:

```
.panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    height: 100%;
}

.panel .panel-content {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.image-responsive {
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Нужно добавить сетку на поле, по котором перемещаются блоки, например, как в `inkscape` или [вот такую](http://d1v8u1ev1s9e4n.cloudfront.net/54e5236f5ccacf314d464817).

Предположим, поле имеет 4 колонки и от 4 до 16 строк. Отображаем 4 вертикальных линий и от 4 до 16 горизонтальных (зависит от размера отображаемой области).
Причем если, например, блок имеет размер 1х1, то при любом размере окна этот блок должен четко занимать 1 клетку в сетке, если 3х2 - то три клетки по горизонтали, и 2 по вертикали соответственно. С другими размерами блоков аналогично.

Пытаюсь сделать через таблицы:
http://jsfiddle.net/qqzvjvfx/18/
Но как учесть то, что поле может увеличиваться по вертикали? Т.е. у него добавляются строки, соответственно, у таблицы для сетки тоже должны добавляться строки. Сейчас же таблица просто растягивается по вертикали.

Через `background-image` - если я правильно понимаю, мне нужно использовать `background-size: cover`. Но по вертикали поле может увеличиваться, соответственно, необходимо добавлять фон по высоте, а не растягивать.
Здесь я добавил вместо таблицы [div](http://jsfiddle.net/qqzvjvfx/21/), как мне прикрутить правильно фон к этому диву, чтобы по горизонтали фон масштабировался (растягивался) в зависимости от ширины этого div (и соответственно ширины поля, на котором перемещаются блоки), а по вертикали повторялся?

Также пытался найти какой-то встроенный функционал в [angular-gridster.js](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster), ведь он подсвечивает области в момент перетаскивания блока, однако поиски пока не увенчались успехом.

**Уточнение:** На сетке необходимо также выделить некую область рамкой [image: пример рамки]
Размер области заранее известен - в ячейках, а не в px.
Поэтому исходя из этого пока использование таблиц удобнее по идее.

**Обновление:**
Вариант с таблицей и динамическим обновлением количества строк http://jsfiddle.net/qqzvjvfx/26/ - отслеживаю изменения в блоках, но блок меняет свою позицию в момент отпускания, а высота поля увеличивается "на всякий случай" заранее, т.е. отслеживать необходимо не ресайз/перемещение блоков, а ресайз общего контейнера гридстера.

обновление 2: http://jsfiddle.net/sfn57eyh/1/ видно, что проблема построения сетки в том, что необходимо знать текущее количество ячеек контейнера по высоте, т.к. оно может меняться. в данном примере из-за этого высота ячеек сетки дергается.

Comment: добавь код как в вопросе на английской версии :-)

Comment: сетка должна быть постоянной? или только в момент перетаскивания?

Comment: @Grundy постоянной

Comment: тогда проще всего нарисовать одну клетку в каком-нибудь svg, чтобы она масштабировалась и сделать ее background с repeat-x, repeat-y или как-то так

Comment: по поводу: _ведь он подсвечивает области в момент перетаскивания блока_ - он просто показывает один div и только в момент перетаскивания

Comment: для варианта с таблицей подписаться на [изменение позиции элемента](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster/blob/master/README.md#watching-item-changes-of-size-and-position) и в обработчике поменять таблицу: увеличить, уменьшить количество строк - столбцов.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, попробую подписаться на изменения и перестраивать таблицу.

Comment: Результат можете как ответ приложить, хотя мне больше нравится идея с _background с repeat-x, repeat-y_ :-)

Comment: @Grundy :) попробовал, результат с таблицей меня не устраивает (таблица дергается при перестраивании), поэтому прикладываю сюда пример http://jsfiddle.net/qqzvjvfx/26/ А с `repeat-y` - не соображу, как лучше сделать, ведь мне нужно соответствие размера клеток `gridster`-a и клеток фона. Т.е. непонятно, как масштабировать фон, чтобы он подгонялся под разметку `gridster`. Попытался отслеживать изменения самого гридстера, через `scope.$on('gridster-resized', function(sizes, gridster){});`, но это событие срабатывает почему-то только в момент старта страницы

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32407/discussion-between-grundy-and-emm).

Comment: Тоже возился с данным компонентом, даже исходники правил. В итоге проще оказалось перевоссоздать функционал при помощи стандартных жквери компонентгов. Если захотите растяжимость, нормальную сетку, вложенность и прочее, в скором времени словите себя на том, что нужные костыли займут больше времени.

Comment: @FLCL какие компоненты посоветуете? нужна сетка, аналогичный ресайз блоков, сортировка аналогично - двумерная (т.е. по горизонтали и по вертикали)

Comment: проекта нет с собой, но суть была такова, что jquery resizable  позволяет квантовать изменение размера и отслеживать промежуточное состояние при его изменении, так я узнавал сколько ячеек сетки надо отрисовать. Как я строил сетку - совсем не помню, вечером гляну, но в итоге её квадраты даже меняли размер, когда я растягивал главный контейнер, содержащий все прямоугольники

Comment: @FLCL сейчас с `angular-gridster` в принципе работает все необходимое, кроме сетки. Переноести все на jquery и потом налажидить дополнительно связь с angular, наверное, займет больше времени, чем написание костыля для сетки? Вы же имеете в виду именно `angular-gridster`, а не `gridster`?

Comment: Если вы уверены, что иных дополнений к стандартному гридстеру вам не потребуется, в таком случае попробуйте что-то типа http://jsfiddle.net/sfn57eyh/

Comment: Может из этого что-то выйдет? 
http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/jWOGOz

Comment: @FLCL спасибо, вроде сетка строится нормально, но при ресайзе контейнера все равно дергается высота ячеек http://jsfiddle.net/sfn57eyh/1/ т.к. гридстер достраивает дополнительные ячейки по высоте, т.е. их количество увеличивается, а у нас делитель остается тем же.

Comment: @NeedHate спасибо, хороший способ, но увы, количество ячеек сетки по высоте может меняться

Comment: А зачем вам вообще разные ширина и высота для ячейки? http://jsfiddle.net/sfn57eyh/2/ тут сетка поправлена до квадратной

Comment: @FLCL спасибо. да, ширина и высота лучше, чтобы была одинаковой. в Вашем примере у меня получается поместить блок посередине ячейки, т.е. граница блока не всегда проходит по границе ячеек, вот скриншот http://s017.radikal.ru/i432/1512/bd/a91f40a03ec5.png

Comment: конечно, ведь гридстер занимает ширину не кратную числу ячеек, но это можно поправить, ограничив ширину гридстер до кратных чисел http://jsfiddle.net/sfn57eyh/7/ , меньше клеток - меньше кванты

Comment: @FLCL, вам стоит оформить ваши комментарии в виде ответа :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов: задать повторяющийся фон из квадратов для главного элемента.

Но, так как размер сетки может меняться, то изображение для фона должно уметь масштабироваться и для этого подходит svg

Например такое (rect2.svg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100pt" height="100pt" viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="#ffffff" style="stroke: #000000; stroke-width: 1"></rect>
</svg>
```

Теперь единственное нужно прописать его в качестве фона, и задать размер - равный размеру ячейки в гридстере. Осталось только определить размер ячейки грида.
Например это можно сделать с помощью своей директивы

```
.directive('mygr', function () {
    return {
        require: 'gridster',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) { //ctrl - контроллер гридстера.
            var w = scope.$watch(function () { return ctrl.curRowHeight }, function (n) {// ждем пока поменяется(будет вычислена) высота строки
                elem.css('background-size',ctrl.curColWidth + 'px ' + ctrl.curRowHeight + 'px');//выставляем background-size
                w();// перестаем наблюдать
            });
        }
    }
});
```

и применяем ее

```
<div gridster="gridsterOpts" mygr="">
```

[Пример, все вместе](http://plnkr.co/edit/hNETnkMrjBcnBwnZ07cA?p=preview)

**Важно:** возможны проблемы с округлением или отрисовкой, поэтому при некоторых условиях. Кроме того возможны проблемы с производительностью из-за использования svg - если размер контейнера большой, а размер сетки - маленький.

Comment: В вашем решении не по граням сетки итемы поставить можно, вероятно движок оперы рисует прямоугольники с округлением.

Comment: @FLCL, да, там это зависит от размеров ячейки, и возможно от округления, которое сам гридстер проводит,

Comment: Если у вас получится решить эту проблему без кастыля в виде внешнего контейнера, то можно даже было бы создать пулл-реквест разрабу, пушто для данного компонента это первая проблема

Comment: @FLCL, тут возможно еще сам svg которой я сделал, не очень. Плюс я смотрел значения которые для него выставляются - там по 5 точек после запятой :-) для данного примера, возможно как раз с этим тоже проблема. У вас же кстати тоже без внешнего контейнера

Comment: С внешним id - d400, поэтому оно и работает

Comment: @FLCL, а я что-то не понял зачем он, можно же было сразу `[gridster="gridsterOpts"]` какой-нибудь использовать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32668/discussion-between-grundy-and-flcl).

Comment: Потому, что если мы хотим ограничивать ширину гридстера так, чтобы она была целыми числами, то мы фиксируем её неким вычисленным значением, и судить о ресайзе можно только по внешнему контейнеру

Comment: @Grundy спасибо! допилил пример - убрал округление, теперь границы блоков совпадают с границами ячеек, и добавил выделение области. В директиве для области добавил проверку на то, изменились ли размеры, чтобы быстрее работал - если каждый раз перерисовывать, скрипт подвисает немного. Наверное, можно аналогично проверку добавить и в первом случае. http://plnkr.co/edit/yuoCouKZ3E1TVjqvvZW6

Comment: Я-то думал, Emm 'у надо выравнеивание по ячейкам, а ему не надо: http://puu.sh/lNOQZ/814c105999.jpg. Зря я заморачивался

Comment: @FLCL, давайте в чат все :) чтобы тут не захламлять

Comment: @FLCL в том примере, который я скинул, масштаб сетки 5х5 ячеек, а блоки можно перемещать и на 1 ячейку. Вот сетка 1х1, чтобы было понятнее http://plnkr.co/edit/Dnlfiew8VYiJ6wJDcUj8 все выравнивается:)

Comment: @Emm http://puu.sh/lOXs6/a95a1f116c.jpg ну, выравнивается, значит выравнивается. У нас, видимо, разные определения данного понятия

Comment: @FLCL, это от размера сетки и размеров контейнера зависит. на конкретных значениях он вполне ровным может быть

Comment: @Grundy, ага и ваше решение не учитывает разные динамически задаваемые ширины при ресайзе окна браузера. попробуйте потягать мой пример и ваш. у меня всегда сетка бить будет и я полагал, в этом суть вопроса, а не просто фон из сетки нарисовать

Comment: @FLCL, про это мы уже в чате говорили :-)

Answer (score 3):

Сетку для гридстера можно добавить при помощи задания css опций `background` для основного контейнера. При этом требуется учесть, что если размер ячейки формировать непосредственно исходя из размера контейнера, то он выйдет не целочисленным и итемы на гридстере будут размещаться не по краям ячеек. Поэтому приходится ограничивать ширину гридстера числами, кратными максимальному количеству ячеек, а опираться на ширину div'а-обёртки. Текстуру фона при этом можно создавать динамически при помощи canvas, либо использовать svg фон. В зависимости от того, как кэшируются оба решения можно выбрать одно из них в плане производительности.

В [решении](http://jsfiddle.net/sfn57eyh/7/) используется `canvas`, результат отрисовки которого попадает в `background`:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = sizeX;
canvas.height = sizeX;
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
context.beginPath();
context.rect(0, 0, sizeX, sizeX);
context.fillStyle = 'white';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.strokeStyle = 'gray';      context.stroke();

$('[gridster="gridsterOpts"]').css(
  "background-image", "url('"+canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')+"')");
```